# Test run on Jenkins Nodes using SSH agent is not showing GUI

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng

I have used cloud bees Jenkins account to setup my build to run on a Jenkins Node machine which is an AWS system(Windows Server 2016). I have setup SSH(port 22) on AWS system using CYGWIN, configured and launched agent on this machine using following launch method:
[image]

Now my tests are running on the Jenkins Node (AWS Machine) but I am not able to see the GUI for it. Please let me know what setting I need to enable to make it visible? also let me know if more details are required.

Comment: What GUI were you expecting to see on the slave?

Comment: Actually the test are running headless.Tests are running on Chrome in backend and we are not able to see it.

Comment: Even more so, running in headless mode means Chrome will run without any graphical interface. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes. Chrome runs without interface.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?